# Prove that for any prime $p$ there exist natural numbers $a,b$ for which $ p$ divides $a^2+b^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, sums-of-squares

Prove that for each prime $p$ there exist natural numbers $a,b$ for which  $p$ divides $a^2+b^2+1$

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried, and whether you have got stuck somewhere so that we can help you with that part.

Comment: I found a,b for every prime <100 but I can't prove it in general

Comment: It's a well known Lemma, and can be found via google search. For its applications, search for Lagrange's theorem on the sum of 4 squares.

Comment: This is often used as a step in the proof  of [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: It's a good question, the voting system doesn't always result in correct judgements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $p>2$, put $A=\{0,1,\ldots,\frac{p-1}{2}\}$ and consider the functions 
$$\begin{align*}f&:A\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p & & g:A\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\\ &\ \ \ \ a\longmapsto a^2 \mod p & & \ \ \ \ \ \ b\longmapsto -b^2-1 \mod p\end{align*}$$

You can easily prove that both functions $f,g$ are injective. Therefore, $|f(A)|=|g(A)|=|A|=\frac{p+1}{2}$, so $f(A),g(A)$ cannot be disjoint because $f(A)\cup g(A)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p$ which has $p$ elements. Thus, there are $a,b\in A$ such that $a^2\equiv -b^2-1 \mod p$, that is, $a^2+b^2+1\equiv 0 \mod p$ and we conclude that $p$ divides $a^2+b^2+1$